Wireguard VPN with WAN failover
I have two sites connected using WireGuard in a hub n spoke topology
Each peer has a redundant WAN connection and the hub has a static IP address
I need the VPN to work when the peer's primary WAN fails and the peer fails over to the backup WAN
Will Wireguard work with WAN failover on the peer?

Does Built-in Roaming look like an answer?
